# Poincaré inequlity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, functional-inequalities

Let $u\in H^1_0((0,1)\times (0,T))$ due to the Poincaré inequality we have for all $t\in [0,T]$:
$$||u(t)||_{L^2(0,1)} \leq ||u_x(t)||_{L^2(0,1)}$$
so in particular, for $t=0$
we will have:
$$||u(0)||_{L^2(0,1)} \leq ||u_x(0)||_{L^2(0,1)}$$
is this statement true?

Comment: Doesn't Poincaré's inequality demand more hypotheses?

Comment: Only bouned set and $(0,1)$ is bounded

Comment: How do you ensure that $ u_x(t) \in L^2(0,1)$?

Comment: @VictorHugo right, I changed the space

Comment: No, because $u(0,.)=u(0)$ for $t=0$ not $x=0$

Comment: I have a question, how do we guarantee that $ u (t, \cdot) \in H_0^1((0,1)) $? Or is that not necessary?